# Can conda install package globally or are all package installed to a specific environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have multiple environments under my conda management, as shown below

```
ss-MacBook-Pro$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /miniconda2
testenv                  /miniconda2/envs/testenv
testenvpy3               /miniconda2/envs/testenvpy3
```

Can I install a package that becomes effective across multiple environments? By reading the [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/), I got the impression that it is NOT possible, because if I do

```
conda install package-name
```

it will only get installed into the `base` environment (the current active environment), but it does not apply to other environments. I remember I can somehow achieve install a package effective to multiple environments under virtualenv before.

Can someone share the suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

`conda install` only installs packages for the current (activated) environment. Files will be installed in the directory for the specific environment. If you want a specific package in all environments, you'll have to `conda install` that package for each of your environments (`base`, `testenv`, `testenvpy3`).

To switch between environments you just need to activate the one you switch to. The syntax depends Anaconda version or your OS. For newer Anaconda versions, `conda activate <env name>` works, and for older versions, `source activate <env name>` for Unix systems and `activate <env name>` for Windows.

I'm sure you've looked at this already, but here's a helpful [link](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).