# How to install to all conda env?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I have 3 conda envs, and I want to install a library using conda install libraryName. is there a way so I can install on all of the conda env at once ?

Comment: Maybe something like this question [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117449/install-a-package-into-multiple-all-conda-environments)

Comment: Or perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067453/can-conda-install-package-globally-or-are-all-package-installed-to-a-specific-en)